# Cables vs. Cabling

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am not sure which term, *cables* or *cabling* (or other), would be more appropriate for the following context:

> A new set of connectors, compatible with the metric ________, would eventually be installed.

My [usual research method](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cable%20vs%20cabling) hasn't been fruitful because the search results are swamped with discussion of which cables are right for specific applications.  [Some searches](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=define%20cabling) for the [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cabling?s=t) of *cabling* even forward me to the definition of *cable*.

When should **cable(s)** vs. **cabling** be used, or are they always interchangeable?

Comment: Ditch the article and go with *compatible with metric **cables***. The gerund form is more suitable for contexts where you're talking about things like *routing* (the *path* the cables take), rather than an actual cable and its connectors.

Comment: Practically, they are the same thing.  I've been in manufacturing for 40 years and see the terms as indistinguishable.  There may be a proper use of these terms but practically there is not.

Comment: Good advise from FumbleFingers.  The gerund is more commonly a mass abstraction (like 'heating') as opposed to a physical set (like heaters).

Comment: basically *cabling* is installed in the wall, whereas *cables* could be installed, on the floor, or still out in the van for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Related Wikipedia article regarding cabling in telecommunications: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_cabling claims:

> Structured cabling is building or campus telecommunications cabling
>   infrastructure that consists of a number of standardized smaller
>   elements (hence structured) called subsystems.

Coming from an engineering background, in my interpretation, cabling *consists of* cables, sockets, plugs, and all other basic, small elements needed to connect *stuff*. I'd even go farther and call the needed work to setup cabling a part of it, similarly to "do the electronics" when building or renovating a house.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI/TIA/EIA 568-B is the *Commercial Building Telecommunications **Cabling** Standard*; however, the [Microsoft Manual of Style, 4th Edition](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXjKnHjcjLAhWGmoMKHZB2BzMQFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Feucalyptus.atlassian.net%2Fwiki%2Fdownload%2Fattachments%2F76611622%2Fmicrosoft_manual_of_style_fourth_edition.pdf%3Fversion%3D2%26modificationDate%3D1424379604164%26api%3Dv2&usg=AFQjCNH4LGu0suDPoWJLSCyhI_3JAdT8Ww) (p.259) states

> **cabling**
>
> ---
>
> Do not use as a synonym for *cable* or *cables*. If necessary in a discussion of network connections, it is all right to use *cabling* to refer to a combination of cables, connectors, and terminators.

while the [Apple Style Guide, April 2013](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiO_qKlksjLAhVmhYMKHX3kC3YQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.apple.com%2Fasg%2Fmac%2F2013%2FASG_2013.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGGAECL7iM542fqhZAZAl-wx6-s6w&bvm=bv.117218890,d.amc) (p.27) states

> **cable** Use *cable* to describe what physically connects two pieces of hardware. Don't use *cabling* even when you mean *cable* collectively; use *cables*.

While I agree with hauron's definition that *cabling* is the systemic combination of cables and components to connect devices, if you asked me to just fill in the blank I would agree with FumbleFingers that the best term here is *cable(s)*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both @hauron and @csperez are correct.  The choice comes down to the OP's intent.  If the sentence is in reference to the use of a one-off connector to a metric cable at a later date, then cables would be correct.  If the sentence is meant to convey that a large scale project that entails multiple connectors to the cabling system at a multitude of locations then cabling would be used.

Answer (score 0):

> [Superior Essex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_Essex) is one of the largest wire and **cable** manufacturers worldwide.

They are a leading manufacturer in the *cable* industry (it's not called the *cabling* industry).

The word *cabling* is all but non-existent on Wiki's [Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable) page. One of the two mentions of *cabling*, directs you to the *twisted pair* page, where it is also used sparsely (the other mention is about *mechanical cabling*).

Here's an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cable%2Ccabling&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccabling%3B%2Cc0) that shows *cable* dwarfing *cabling*. IMO, *cabling* is the installed product (and all its odds and ends). A *cable* is what you purchase to install. Note that according to most dictionaries however, they're largely interchangeable as both verbs and nouns.